# Android adding view from java side

Tags: android

My xml is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

  <View         
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"         
    android:layout_height="3dp"         
    android:paddingTop="20dp"         
    android:background="#000088" />


  <RelativeLayout  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal">   


  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/employeename"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="11pt"
     android:padding="5dip"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textColor="#000033"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
     android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/employeestn"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="11pt"
     android:padding="5dip"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textColor="#000033"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
     android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
     android:text ="TUL"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />

 </RelativeLayout>
<ListView 
     android:id="@+id/mytasklist"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:divider="#B2B0BF"
     android:dividerHeight="10px"
     android:background="#FFFFFF"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am having two textviews and a listview. I may or may not have another list depending on data. My page can have max of 3 list views. Can I add another listview from java side ? How? -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Appreciate help

Comment: why -1 ? What's wrong with my question

Answer (score 0):

You can define the 3rd ListView in your XML and make it initially invisible in your XML. Then depending on your data you can populate it and make it visible.